# How to generate seperate css bundles for multipage app using webpack 2.0 and extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

> When using webpack, a common requirement to generate bunldes for multipage app, is to bundle the common modules and the third party modules seperately.

I've made it with javascript sources. **However, not with the style sources**.

#### Here is my sample repo: https://github.com/e-cloud/webpack-multipage-tester and it [webpack.config](https://github.com/e-cloud/webpack-multipage-tester/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

The demo project has two entrypoints: `home` and `catagory`.
I use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and `CommonChunksPlugin` to split the bundles.

I manage to generate js chunks(`vendor.js` `home.js` `catagory.js` `commons.js`) and css chunks(`catagory.css`,`home.css`,`commons.css`).

but the wanted third-party css library `hint.css` isn't bunlded into `commons.css`, but into `catagory.css`, `home.css` and even `vendor.js`.

---

#### Here is the [dependencies map](https://rawgit.com/e-cloud/webpack-multipage-tester/master/dependency-graph.png):

[image: dependencies]

#### And below is the [bundle graph](https://rawgit.com/e-cloud/webpack-multipage-tester/master/bundle-map.png):

[image: map]

#### The [expected result](https://rawgit.com/e-cloud/webpack-multipage-tester/master/perfect-target.png) is:(hint.css is the key point)

[image: expected]